# Difficulty Isolating Variable in Trig Equation

Tags: trigonometry

I need to isolate $g$ in the equation below. Is it possible? If so, how?

> $$\begin{align}
> f = 90^\circ + g &{}+ \arctan\left(\frac{r\cos(i+g)}{k - r \sin(i+g)}\right) \\[5pt]
> &{} - \arccos\left(\frac{r^2 - (k - 2 r\sin g)^2 + \left(\dfrac{k - r\sin(i+g)}{\cos\arctan\left(\dfrac{r\cos(i+g)}{k - r\sin(i+g)}\right)}\right)^2}{\dfrac{2r(k - r\sin(i+g))}{\cos\arctan\left(\dfrac{r\sin(i+g)}{k r \sin(i+g)}\right)}}\right)
> \end{align}$$

TeXification by @Blue. Double-check against the [source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnrHm.jpg).

Comment: Nope, probably not. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation

Comment: Do you know that $\cos(\arctan(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ ? This can slightly simplify your expression. Nevertheless, like my colleague @Lovsovs, I doubt very much that you can extract $g$ out of this magma. Numerical methods...

Comment: Just checking: You have a couple of instances of $$\frac{r\cos(i+g)}{k - r\sin(i+g)}$$ but in the denominator of the denominator of the second term you have something *close* but different. Could there be a typo?

Comment: It would probably help if you provided the image from which your expression derives. There may be much-simpler ways of expressing the relations among the elements.